# docker php:5.6.40 official image xdebug

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I need to get the old PHP app debugging to work (requires PHP 5.6). At the moment app runs in a container built from php:5.6.40 official image.

The app is running in server: 192.168.1.182:8100

The VS Code host IP is: 192.168.1.239

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6.40-apache

RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch-proposed-updates main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update

# Install minimal packages to build Xdebug
 RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libzip-dev git
 RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

# Install Xdebug from the source
RUN git clone -b XDEBUG_2_5_5 https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git /root/xdebug \
&& cd /root/xdebug && ./rebuild.sh

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysql
```

php.ini xdebug config

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.239
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/www/html
xdebug.remote_log="./xdebug.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=1
```

I need to debug it xdebug 2.5.5 (in NetBeans I managed to get debugging to work, but endless Socket Exception made it useless). Therefore, I'm trying to switch to VS Code.

VS Code debugging launch config:

```
"configurations": [
                {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html":"W:/intra/php/intra"
            }, 
            "log": true           
        }
    ]
```

What else do I have to do to get debugging work?